# Group by in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I achieve from this table result:

[image]

And I want to achieve this:

[image]

I tried a query with `group by` statement but I can't calculate 'wartosc_netto' correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `group by` and a `sum` will do I guess:

```
select id_zamowienia
,      login
,      imie
,      sum(wartosc_netto) wartosc_netto
from   tableName
group
by     id_zamowienia
,      login
,      imie
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT id_zamowiena, login, imie, SUM(wartosc_netto)
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY id_zamowiena, login, imie
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id_zamowienia, login, imie, sum(wartosc_netto) AS wartosc_netto
FROM myTable
GROUP BY id_zamowienia # or login, or imie, depending on what you want to do
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select id_zamowienia, login, imie, sum(wartosc_netto) from <table>  group by id_zamowienia, login, imie
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
SELECT id_z...., SUM(wartosc_netto)
       FROM table_name
      GROUP BY id_z....;
```